# Hiding layers in Visio with VBA

Tags: vba

I created (basically) an organizational chart in Visio with  different levels and want to be able to hide the levels with the press of a button. If I hide level 1 (= top level), all levels below it have to be hidden too because it is a hierarchy.

The reason I'm posting this for review is that I'm not sure I chose the best approach: I assigned the different levels in the hierarchy to different layers. The layers' names need to be standardized, namely 'Layer' + Number (01, 02, etc.) + (optional) LayerName. The number in the layer name corresponds to the hierarchy in the Visio-chart and allows the code to know which layer to hide, i.e. it allows it to identify which layers are below it in the hierarchy.

In Visio each shape gets assigned to its respective layer, in the sample code it's "Layer01 - Level1", "Layer12- Level2", "Layer13 - Level3". For each level of the hierarchy there's a button to hide that level and it gets assigned a sub `ToggleLevel` which delivers the name of the layer to the main sub. From there it goes through some checks to see if the layers are named correctly, extracts the number in the layer name and puts layer number and layer name into a dictionary - I could have used an array for the layer number, but maybe having the layer name can be used at some point.

The `MainSub` then hides all layers whose number is equal to or bigger than (= lower in the hierarchy) the number of the target layer (= layer for which the macro was triggered).

```
Option Explicit

Sub ToggleLevel1()
    MainSub ("Layer01 - Level1")
End Sub

Sub ToggleLevel2()
    MainSub ("Layer12- Level2")
End Sub

Sub ToggleLevel3()
    MainSub ("Layer13 - Level3")
End Sub


Private Sub MainSub(layerName As String)
    Dim iKey As Variant
    Dim layerDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim targetLayerNumber As Long

    Set layerDict = CreateLayerDict
    Call UnhideAllLayers
    
    targetLayerNumber = GetLayerNumber(layerName)
    
    'hide all layers with layer number equal to or larger than the target layer
    For Each iKey In layerDict.Keys
        If targetLayerNumber <= iKey Then
            Call HideLayer(layerDict(iKey))
        End If
    Next iKey

End Sub


Private Sub HideLayer(layerName As String)
    ActivePage.Layers(layerName).CellsC(visLayerVisible).FormulaU = 0
End Sub


Sub UnhideAllLayers()
    Dim layerIterator As Variant

    For Each layerIterator In ActivePage.Layers
        Debug.Print layerIterator
        layerIterator.CellsC(visLayerVisible).FormulaU = 1
    Next layerIterator
End Sub


Private Function CreateLayerDict()
    Dim iLayer As Variant
    Dim iLayerNumber As Long
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    For Each iLayer In ActivePage.Layers()
        Debug.Print iLayer.name
        Call CheckLayerName(iLayer.name)
        iLayerNumber = GetLayerNumber(iLayer.name)
        dict.Add iLayerNumber, iLayer.name
    Next iLayer
    
    Set CreateLayerDict = dict
End Function


'===============Naming convention======================================
                 'Layer + Number + (optional) Name:
                    'Layer01, Layer02..., Layer10, Layer11, etc.
                    'Layer06 - CEO, Layer07 - Middle Management, etc.
'====================================================================

Private Sub CheckLayerName(name As String)
    'Layer name too short
    If Len(name) < 7 Then
        MsgBox "Layer name needs to be at least six characters long (Layer plus layer number)." & Chr(10) & "Macro will end."
        End
    End If
    
    'Layer name does not contain a number as sixth character
    If Not Mid(name, 6, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
        MsgBox "Sixth character in layer name needs to be a number (layer count)." & Chr(10) & "Macro will end."
        End
    End If
    
    'Layer name does not contain a number as seventh character
    If Not Mid(name, 7, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
        MsgBox "Seventh character in layer name needs to be a number (layer count)." & Chr(10) & "Macro will end."
        End
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetLayerNumber(name As String) As Long
    Dim layName As String
    Dim lenName As Long
    
    layName = ActivePage.Layers(1).name
   
    If Mid(name, 6, 1) = 0 Then                 'Layer number between 1 and 9
        GetLayerNumber = CLng(Mid(name, 7, 1))
    Else                                        'Layer number is 10 or above
        GetLayerNumber = CLng(Mid(name, 6, 2))
    End If
End Function
```

**edit** Leading zero **edit**

@BZngr: Returning `Mid(s1, 6, 2)` from a function eliminates the leading zero and thus the layer 01-09 fail the test for the correct name format. Here my test for it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    
    s1 = "Layer03"
    s2 = "Layer12"
    
    If Mid(s1, 6, 2) Like "##" Then
        Debug.Print "Layer number found."
        Debug.Print "Number: " & Mid(s1, 6, 2)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Layer number not found."
    End If
    
    If TestGetLayerNumber(s1) Like "##" Then
        Debug.Print "With Function: Layer number found."
        Debug.Print "Number with function: " & TestGetLayerNumber(s1)
    Else
        Debug.Print "With Function: Layer number not found."
        Debug.Print "Number with function: " & TestGetLayerNumber(s1)
    End If
    
    
End Sub


Private Function TestGetLayerNumber(ByVal layerName As String) As Long
'    TestGetLayerNumber = CLng(Mid(layerName, 6, 2))

    TestGetLayerNumber = Mid(layerName, 6, 2)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not a software solution/approach is the 'best' is always difficult to say.  The aphorism "Make if work, make it right, make it fast" (Kent Beck) pretty much sums up a process of code development that produces good results.  Since this code 'works', posting here in CR would imply that you're looking for input regarding the next 'make it right' phase.  Of course, 'right' is a very subjective standard.  Still, there are certain design/implementation best practices that make some code *better* that others.

**Naming Things:**

"There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." (Phil Karlton)

Software is read far more often that it is written.  Code that names variables and functions in ways that express their purpose improves the speed of understanding for someone (like a CR reviewer) to understand the code's purpose.

For example:

```
'Original code
Sub ToggleLevel3()
    MainSub ("Layer13 - Level3")
End Sub

Private Sub MainSub(layerName As String)
    '{...}
End Sub
```

The subroutine name `MainSub` provides no useful information about the purpose of the subroutine.  Rather than `MainSub`, the following would be more descriptive:

```
Sub ToggleLevel3()
    ToggleLayerVisibility ("Layer13 - Level3")
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleLayerVisibility(layerName As String)
    {...}
End Sub
```

Within `ToggleLayerVisibility` there is a function call to `CreateLayerDict` that assigns a variable `layerDict`.  From these names, the reader would reasonably assume that there a `Dictionary` of data that, when created, is useful to the subroutine.

Unfortunately, neither the variable nor the function name help the reader know what the `Dictionary` contains. The reader has to go look at `CreateLayerDict` in order to figure out what the `Dictionary` contains.  Changing the name of the variable to something like `layerNamesByLayerNumber` would describe the output/purpose of the `CreateLayerDict` function.

There is a loop at the end of the subroutine that uses a variable name `iKey`.  The statement `For Each XXX In layerNamesByLayerNumber.Keys` already tells the reader that the code block is iterating on the `layerNamesByLayerNumber` keys.  The variable `iKey` does not add information or improve readability.  `layerNumber` would be a better name. The name of `CreateLayerDict` can be improved as well.

```
Private Sub ToggleLayerVisibility(layerName As String)

    Dim layerNamesByLayerNumber As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set layerNamesByLayerNumber = OrganizeLayersByLayerNumber()
    
    UnhideAllLayers
    
    Dim targetLayerNumber As Long
    targetLayerNumber = GetLayerNumber(layerName)
    
    'hide all layers with layer number equal to or larger than the target layer
    Dim layerNumber As Variant
    For Each layerNumber In layerNamesByLayerNumber.Keys
        If targetLayerNumber <= layerNumber Then
            HideLayer(layerNamesByLayerNumber(layerNumber))
        End If
    Next iKey

End Sub
```

Notes:

1. Some variable declarations have been moved. VBA code within procedures is often written such that all variable are declared at the top of the procedure.  Module level variable declarations are required by VBA language to appear at the top of a module (before any procedure declarations).  *Within* procedures, however, there is no such requirement.  It is a best/better practice within procedures to declare variables as close as reasonably possible to where they are first used.
2. `Call` is deprecated and not necessary for the code to work.

**Prefer descriptively-named methods to comments:**
In the code above, the comment above the `For Each` code block is interesting.  The comment, though accurate, does not match the *way* in which the logic achieves the correct result.  It is easier for the reader to map the comment to the code when `If targetLayerNumber <= layerNumber Then` is changed to `If layerNumber >= targetLayerNumber Then`.

Further, it is always an improvement to readability if a comment can be replaced with a well-named method.  So, consider the following implementation of `ToggleLayerVisibility`:

```
Private Sub ToggleLayerVisibility(layerName As String)

    Dim layerNamesByLayerNumber As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set layerNamesByLayerNumber = OrganizeLayersByLayerNumber()
    
    Call UnhideAllLayers
    
    Dim targetLayerNumber As Long
    targetLayerNumber = GetLayerNumber(layerName)
    
    HideLayersWhereLayerNumberIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo targetLayerNumber, layerNamesByLayerNumber
    
End Sub

Private Sub HideLayersWhereLayerNumberIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo (ByVal targetLayerNumber As Long, _ 
    ByVal layerNamesByLayerNumber As Scripting.Dictionary)
    
    Dim layerNumber As Variant
    For Each layerNumber In layerNamesByLayerNumber.Keys
        If layerNumber >= targetLayerNumber Then
            HideLayer(layerNamesByLayerNumber(layerNumber))
        End If
    Next iKey
End Sub
```

Admittedly, a very long name for the new subroutine (but shorter than the comment!).  By introducing a subroutine, the reader is no longer drawn into the details of a `For Each` loop.  And now, the main subroutine `ToggleLayerVisibility` contains statements that, in plain English, describes the actions needed to 'toggle layer visibility'.

**Single Responsibility Principal:**

When the reader looks into `OrganizeLayersByLayerNumber/CreateLayerDict`, he will discover that this function does something far beyond the *stated* scope of creating a `Dictionary`.  During the process of creating the `Dictionary`, `OrganizeLayersByLayerNumber` calls `CheckLayerName` which might also interact with the user and abruptly `End` the program.

`OrganizeLayersByLayerNumber` includes a validation responsibility in addition to creating a `Dictionary`.  Combining multiple responsibilities in a single function is inconsistent with the Single Responsibility Principal ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)).

Typically, validation and early termination (because of validation failure) occur at the earliest possible place in a program.  So, incorporating these ideas in `ToggleLayerVisibility` would look like:

```
Private Sub ToggleLayerVisibility(layerName As String)

    If Not ActivePageHasValidLayerNames() Then
        MsgBox "Not all Layer Names are of the form 'Layer## - <name>'"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim layerNamesByLayerNumber As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set layerNamesByLayerNumber = OrganizeLayersByLayerNumber()
    
    UnhideAllLayers
    
    Dim targetLayerNumber As Long
    targetLayerNumber = GetLayerNumber(layerName)
    
    HideLayersWhereLayerNumberIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo targetLayerNumber, layerNamesByLayerNumber
    
End Sub
```

`ActivePageHasValidLayerNames` contains all the validation code - but *does not* include termination code.  Something like:

```
Private Function ActivePageHasValidLayerNames() As Boolean

    ActivePageHasValidLayerNames= True
    
    Dim pageLayer As Variant
    For Each pageLayer In ActivePage.Layers
        If Not IsValidLayerName(pageLayer.Name) Then
            ActivePageHasValidLayerNames= False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next pageLayer

End Sub

Private Function IsValidLayerName(layerName As String) As Boolean

    IsValidLayerName = False
    
    'Layer name too short
    If Len(layerName) < 7 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'Layer name does not contain a number as sixth and seventh characters
    If Not Mid(layerName, 6, 2) Like "##" Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    IsValidLayerName = True
End Sub
```

Now that the validation responsibility of `OrganizeLayersByLayerNumber/CreateLayerDict` has been extracted, it no longer looks like creating a `Dictionary` is necessary.  `HideLayersWhereLayerNumberIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo` can now be implemented as:

```
Private Sub HideLayersWhereLayerNumberIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo (ByVal targetLayerNumber As Long)
    
    Dim pageLayer As Variant
    For Each pageLayer In ActivePage.Layers()
        'GetLayerNumber can be called safely since all layer names are validated
        layerNumber = GetLayerNumber(pageLayer.name)
        If layerNumber >= targetLayerNumber Then
            HideLayer pageLayer.name
        End If
    Next iLayer
    
End Sub
```

Putting it all together:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ToggleLevel1()
    ToggleLayerVisibility "Layer01 - Level1"
End Sub

Sub ToggleLevel2()
    ToggleLayerVisibility "Layer12- Level2"
End Sub

Sub ToggleLevel3()
    ToggleLayerVisibility "Layer13 - Level3"
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleLayerVisibility(layerName As String)

    If Not ActivePageHasValidLayerNames() Then
        MsgBox "Not all Layer Names are of the form 'Layer## - <name>'"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    UnhideAllLayers
    
    Dim targetLayerNumber As Long
    targetLayerNumber = GetLayerNumber(layerName)
    
    HideLayersWhereLayerNumberIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo targetLayerNumber
    
End Sub

Sub UnhideAllLayers()
    Dim pageLayer As Variant
    For Each pageLayer In ActivePage.Layers
        Debug.Print pageLayer 
        pageLayer .CellsC(visLayerVisible).FormulaU = 1
    Next pageLayer 
End Sub

Private Sub HideLayersWhereLayerNumberIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo (ByVal targetLayerNumber As Long)
    
    Dim pageLayer As Variant
    For Each pageLayer In ActivePage.Layers()
        layerNumber = GetLayerNumber(pageLayer.name)
        If layerNumber >= targetLayerNumber Then
            HideLayer pageLayer.name
        End If
    Next iLayer
    
End Sub

Private Function ActivePageHasValidLayerNames() As Boolean

    ActivePageHasValidLayerNames= True
    
    Dim pageLayer As Variant
    For Each pageLayer In ActivePage.Layers
        If Not IsValidLayerName(pageLayer.name) Then
            ActivePageHasValidLayerNames= False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next pageLayer

End Sub

Private Function IsValidLayerName(ByVal layerName As String) As Boolean

    IsValidLayerName = False
    
    'Layer name too short
    If Len(layerName) < 7 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'Layer name does not contain a number as sixth and seventh characters
    If Not Mid(layerName, 6, 2) Like "##" Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    IsValidLayerName = True
End Sub

Private Function GetLayerNumber(ByVal layerName As String) As Long
    GetLayerNumber = CLng(Mid(layerName, 6, 2))
End Function

Private Sub HideLayer(ByVal layerName As String)
    ActivePage.Layers(layerName).CellsC(visLayerVisible).FormulaU = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is so valuable for me. 

I'll go through all the points you made and will integrate them into my code, but right now I'm having an issue getting the sub `IsValidLayerName` to work. `If Not GetLayerNumber(layerName) Like "##"` does not work because VBA eliminates the leading zero (no matter if I use `CLng` or not). This does not happen when I don't put `CLng(Mid(layerName, 6, 2))` in a separate function.

Comment: @Alex My mistake...sorry.  I've corrected the `Like` expression in `IsValidLayerName`.

Comment: `GetLayerNumber()` returns a `Long` which is why the leading '0' is removed.  The `Like` operator should be used with a `String`.